# Lighttpd: Can I redirect an http error response to an error.php handler?

Tags: php, error-handling, lighttpd

I edited my *lighttpd.conf* as follows and restarted the service:

```
server.error-handler = "/var/www/error.php"
```

In an *example.php* file, I create the following code:

```
<?php 

http_response_code(404);

?>
```

My expectation was that upon loading *example.php* in the browser, I would be redirected to the */var/www/error.php* handler. However, nothing happened. Is this kind of functionality even possible? Is there a way to do this such that it works?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the lighttpd documentation on the official lighttpd website?

[lighttpd Configuration Options](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ConfigurationOptions)

I believe that you are looking for lighttpd configuration option `server.error-intercept`

However, if you want to intercept HTTP status 4xx and 5xx from PHP pages, then a more performant soluion is to do so in your PHP, calling a library in your PHP rather than going back and forth from lighttpd.